# How can I pretty print a PersistentHashMap in Clojure to a string?

Tags: clojure

How can I pretty print a PersistentHashMap in Clojure to a string? I am looking for something like:

```
(str (pprint {... hash map here...})
```

which I can pass around as a String

Comment: (str (pprint {:foo 1 :bar 2})) works for me => {:foo 1, :bar 2}

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
user=> (import java.io.StringWriter)
java.io.StringWriter
user=> (use '[clojure.pprint :only (pprint)])
nil
user=> (defn hashmap-to-string [m] 
  (let [w (StringWriter.)] (pprint m w)(.toString w)))
#'user/hashmap-to-string
user=> (hashmap-to-string {:a 1 :b 2})
"{:a 1, :b 2}\n"
```

Comment: The compiler complains "CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: w in this context". The original post works but Rayne's edits seem to have broken it!

Answer (score 47):

```
(let [s (java.io.StringWriter.)]
  (binding [*out* s]
    (clojure.pprint/pprint {:a 10 :b 20}))
  (.toString s))
```

Edit: Equivalent succinct version:

```
(with-out-str (clojure.pprint/pprint {:a 10 :b 20}))
```

Comment: You can also use with-out-str, which cuts out all the binding stuff.

Comment: will this work if other threads output to *out*. Is it threadsafe?

Comment: @Zubair - The binding macro is always thread safe. The new var binding is created on a per thread basis and the root binding is unchanged. See http://clojure.org/vars

Comment: @Rayne Thanks for mentioning. I could not find with-out-str on clojuredocs in the first pass, but can see it there now. So, the updated solution is this: (with-out-str (clojure.pprint/pprint {:a 10 :b 20}))

Comment: Please post this last comment as an answer - it's easy to miss ;)

Comment: Convenient macro:

    (defmacro pprint-str 
      [forms]
      `(with-out-str (clojure.pprint/pprint (do ~forms))))

Answer (score 20):

This should help:

```
(clojure.pprint/write {:a 1 :b 2} :stream nil)
```

according to clojure.pprint/write [documentation](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.pprint/write)

> Returns the string result if :stream is nil or nil otherwise.

Comment: Works in ClojureScript. Excellent answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
(pr-str {:a 1 :b 2}) ;; => "{:a 1, :b 2}"
```

Comment: I tried this but I could only get it to work from the REPL. What should I import for this to work from within a program?

Comment: pr-str is part of the clojure.core namespace. You shouldn't have to import anything special.

Comment: Yep, you're right, I was doing it wrong. It works now, except (pr-str {:a 1 :b {:a 2 :b 2}}) returns {:a 1, :b {:a 2, :b 2}}. Is there any way to get it to return this with carriage returns in it?

Comment: `pr-str` is not designed to 'pretty print' (e.g. with newlines).

Comment: `prn-str` includes newlines in the returned string.