# Pretty print to a string in ClojureScript?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

How does one use `cljs.pprint` to return a string?

```
(cljs.pprint/pprint '(foo bar))
```

Would like this to return a string, rather than have a side effect of printing it.

Similar to this question, but for CLJS, not CLJ.

[How can I pretty print a PersistentHashMap in Clojure to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555496/how-can-i-pretty-print-a-persistenthashmap-in-clojure-to-a-string)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This should work:

```
(with-out-str (cljs.pprint/pprint '(foo bar)))
```

Comment: This is great, there's also some additional tweaks to control behavior, e.g.`cljs(binding [cljs.pprint/`

Comment: If you want this in HTML, remember to use `<pre>` and `<code>` or CSS `whitespace: pre`.